# What did Mark Watney type about his cussing?

Tags: movie, the-martian

Right after he started communicating with Earth, Mark was warned (by Mission Control) that he needed to to stop cussing because the whole world could hear him.

**What did he type as a response?**

Comment: Is this from *The Martian*?

Comment: I felt that my answer to this one was pretty convincing, covering both the source novel and the film script. Is there anything else you'd like me to add before considering an acceptance?

Answer (score 38):

In the [source novel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Martian_(Weir_novel)) it was the text emoticon for breasts.

> [12:04] JPL: We’ll get botanists in to ask detailed questions and double-check your work. Your life is at stake, so we want to be sure. Sol 900 is great news. It’ll give us a lot more time to get the supply mission together. Also, please watch your language. Everything you type is being broadcast live all over the world.
>
> [12:15] WATNEY: Look! A pair of boobs! -> ( . Y . )

In Drew Goddard's [earlier version of the script](http://s3.foxfilm.com/foxmovies/dev/films/104/assets/the_martian_screenplay.pdf-9551349672.pdf?ref_=ac_ac_ac_acd_scr_cap_pri_2) it was a **lot ruder**.

> The whole room waits patiently. Tim reads the response.
>
> **TIM:** *He says... **“They don’t know I’m alive? What the--” (hesitates) 
>   “What the... f-word... f-word in gerund form... f-word again... is wrong with
>   you... f-words.”***
>
> **Venkat:** *Mark, please watch your language. Everything you type is being broadcast live all over the
>   world*
>
> Mark’s eyes narrow as he types his response. Hits ENTER
>
> The group reads Mark's response. They go PALE. Oh, Jesus.  Venkat
>   hangs his head. Tim tries really hard not to smile and fails.
>
> Teddy is on the phone as Mitch approaches.
>
> **TEDDY (INTO PHONE):** *Yes sir... he's under a tremendous amount of stress... I understand. We're working on it. Thank you, sir.*
>
> Teddy hangs up. Glances at Mitch.
>
> **TEDDY (CONT'D):** *I just had to explain to the President of the United States what a “**bureaucratic [felcher](https://static.tumblr.com/f02149c4f22ac451df0e24ff0574f649/rpiwkvj/YVjnqobnz/tumblr_static_1yxckczkgq68s4ckcc0c80cc.png)**” is.*

Comment: I remember being saddened when they only alluded to this in the movie, but I had to admit that it worked as well if not better as a joke by not revealing it.

Comment: @Broklynite - I agree. They seem to have toyed with leaving it in, making it ruder, then finally decided just to have it be a [react](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Funny/React) gag.

Comment: @Valorium - it worked well that way ... but of course in my _head_ was `(.Y.)`

Comment: (I see now for the first time that it works _even better_ in a monospaced font ...)

Comment: @davidbak - I added spaces to make the boobies bigger. It stops them from looking lopsided (in the font) but I'm concerned for the integrity of the original writing.

Comment: monospace the boobies? `(.Y.)`

Comment: I once watched a youtube clip which did show how he responded. Unfortunately I can't find it again right now. Does anyone have a link to that youtube clip?

Answer (score 3):

In the novel Mark writes "Look! A pair of boobs -> ( .Y . )"

Although in the original serial posted to Andy's website it was something about felching (don't look that up please) and a blooper scene leads me to believe they almost went with that in the movie because it's a scene of Teddy explaining what felching is to Annie (again don't look it up if you don't already know) and then everyone laughs.